# Zero padding between values in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have problem during low-pass interpolation, I have to fill 1D array with zeros before processing it.

I have something like this: [1 2 3 4 5 6]

I want to have array like this [1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6] so it is L-1 zeros in array where L is the number of all values inside array before zero stuffing.

How to do it in Python?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can assign an unpadded list of values into a slice of another list of zeros:

```
original_list = range(1,7)                 # [1,2,3,4,5,6]
padded_list = [0]*(2*len(original_list)-1) # [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
padded_list[::2] = original_list           # [1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6]
```

This can translate to `numpy` too, though as Jaime pointed out in a comment, it's even easier to use `numpy.insert`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(1, 7)              # array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
np.insert(arr, slice(1, None), 0)  # array([1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6])
```

Comment: Is slice(1,None,2) right? For me (1,None,1) was resulting in the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

I had to apply that for bigger amount of data real time, so I checked the performance and np.insert seems to be the slowest one on Python 2.7:

```
np.insert:                     1.393 ms
list:                          0.406 ms
np.repeat then zero out:       0.409 ms
np.zeros then assign value:    0.073 ms
```

Here's the test code:

```
import time
import numpy as np

start = 0
limit = 30000000

def tic():
    global start
    start = time.clock()

def toc(text):
    print("%-30s %.3f ms" % (text, time.clock()-start))

original_list = range(1,limit)
original_array = np.arange(1, limit)

tic()
insert_array = np.insert(original_array, slice(1, None), 0)
toc("np.insert:")

tic()
padded_list = [0]*(2*len(original_list)-1)
padded_list[::2] = original_list
toc("list:")

tic()
repeat_array = np.repeat(original_array, 2)
repeat_array[1::2] = 0
toc("np.repeat then zero out:")

tic()
padded_array = np.zeros(2*len(original_list)-1, dtype=original_array.dtype)
padded_array[::2] = original_array
toc("np.zeros then assign value:")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

def zero_pad(l):
    r = []
    for x in l:
        r.append(x)
        r.append(0)
    return r[:-1]

print zero_pad(l)
```

Will print:

```
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

One simplistic approach:

```
>>> i = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> [i.insert(i.index(x)+1,0) for x in i[:-1]]
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>> i
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6]
```

The same as above, expanded:

```
>>> for x in i[:-1]:
...     i.insert(i.index(x)+1,0)
...
>>> i
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6]
```

Comment: There's no good reason to use the list comprehension version. The explicit loop is much easier to understand, and doesn't build a useless list of `None`s.

Comment: Actually, as I read this again, there's a bit more wrong. Using `i.index` is not necessary, and it will give the wrong results if there are duplicate values in the list. Since you know that you want to insert a zero at every position in reverse order you should just use `for x in range(len(i)-1,0,-1): i.insert(x, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
def zero(array):
    for i in range(1, len(array)):
        array.insert(i+i-1,0)
    return array

array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
newArray = zero(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mandatory `itertools` approach:

```
>>> from itertools import izip, repeat, chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(izip(el, repeat(0))))[:-1]
[1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6]
```

Much better `itertools` approach...

```
from itertools import islice, izip, repeat, chain
blah = list (islice (chain.from_iterable (izip(repeat (0), your_seq)), 1, None))
```